# Javascript - date input in Safari - Validation: 31 of February Year

Tags: javascript, date, validation

How can I validate the date of 31/02/any year in Safari?

In Chrome or Firefox, it can be validated by the attribute validity.badInput but in Safari is not working.

Let's suppose I have a date field in a form and the field is not required but I want to know if the user fills in a wrong date such as: 31/02/2000 or 31/09/2000.

PS. Keep in mind that the value of the field is value="" if the date is wrong.

Comment: you can use a date picker. So the user has to select a valid date and in the server, you will check the validity of the input value.

Comment: Assuming you're using an input type date, if the value entered is not a valid date then `isNaN(new Date(input.value))` returns *true*.